# Must Compile Message and Service Several Times To Work

Tags: ros, catkin-make, include, service, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks (sorry for the upper case in advance...they just to make sure people understand those are **examples** of my code),

What is the proper way to create a CMakeList.txt file that includes messages and services? Every time I create a new group of messages or services and include them in my code, for **EXAMPLE**,

```
"my_package_msgs/MessageOrService.h"
```

it always takes a few "catkin_makes" for my system to recognize the library. Here is my CMakeList file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(message_package_msgs)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
  geometry_msgs
  sensor_msgs
)
add_message_files(
  DIRECTORY
    msg
  FILES
    Message_EXAMPLE.msg
)
add_service_files(
  DIRECTORY
    srv
  FILES
    Service_EXAMPLE.srv
)
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  sensor_msgs
)
catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime geometry_msgs sensor_msgs
include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

And my package.xml with the build/run only:

```
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>sensor_msgs</build_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>sensor_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>geometry_msgs</run_depend>
```

What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239352/must-compile-message-and-service-several-times-to-work/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to add dependencies to your library / executable targets on the target which generates the code for the messages and services. Please see the last two code snippets in the documentation: http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format1/building_msgs.html

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-07-12**:
groovay...